# Embedding excel workbook on a website

Tags: excel, embed, interactive

I have a payroll excel workbook that I want to embed on our company intranet in order so that employees can open the page, fill out the appropriate cells in the spreadsheet and print it out. The workbook has countless pages and is filled with macros so simply recreating the table in HTML wont work. I have attempted to use Skydrive to do this but unfortunately the workbook is excel 93-2007 format which is unsupported for embedding. What is another way to go about doing this? Ideally I would like to have it on its own page, viewable in an iframe.

Comment: Why don't you just link to the file on the website: why does it need to show in the browser ?

Comment: For no other reason other than stylistically I would prefer it that way

Answer (score 0):

Is very simple., save the excel in another version -2007 or 2010 and that's it.

Comment: I would do that if I could but saving in another format causes the macros in place to not work correctly. Also those pages are protected which is not supported by Skydrive. As of now I do not have authorization to change these features and so finding an alternative solution is necessary.